# Deshacerme de lineas cuando las valores estan 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe con fechas y valores de empresas. Sin embargo tengo las valores tambien durante los week-ends y me gustaria deshacerme de ellos porque estan 0:

```
    MCD.BA  MAQ.AX  BEKB.BR BRSR6.SA    EMBR3.SA    CWX.TO  UG.PA   VOW.F   DG.PA   VK.PA   EDL.F   TNE2.F  SRB.F   BEI.DE  BMT.SG  BSU.SG  D6H.DE  B5A.DE  3328.HK 0129.HK 3368.HK 1988.HK 3378.HK 1099.HK ANSALHSG.NS WSTCSTPAPR.NS   DATAMATICS.NS   ADANIENT.NS CIR.MI  FRAGUAB.MX  GD.MX   CL.MX   TEL.OL  BS6.SI  ITX.MC  EKTA-B.ST   3617.TW AVT CUK BEN MSFT    QCOM    IHG.L   ASHM.L  SGRO.L  BA  CAR MC.PA   RMS CDI.PA  TIF BRBY.L
2020-08-13  6734.5  45.310001   17.389999   13.80   7.60    6.81    15.300  150.899994  81.980003   30.320000   1.74    3.60    66.489998   96.800003   28.889999   20.200001   56.900002   9.88    4.33    0.90    0.275   4.98    0.91    18.740000   4.35    187.050003  64.150002   200.750000  0.400   225.0   3500.0  1718.800049 148.449997  0.955   24.10   98.000000   78.599998   28.230000   13.05   21.879999   208.699997  113.410004  4226.0  428.200012  963.200012  174.729996  31.190001   391.200012  0.0 352.600006  124.800003  1421.5
2020-08-14  6618.5  45.980000   17.270000   13.63   7.68    6.90    15.095  150.000000  80.379997   29.809999   1.70    3.66    66.330002   95.660004   28.365000   19.799999   57.000000   9.81    4.30    0.92    0.275   4.97    0.92    18.780001   4.20    184.000000  62.150002   196.199997  0.398   225.0   3500.0  1718.800049 147.000000  0.950   23.68   97.559998   78.500000   28.370001   13.07   21.950001   208.899994  113.739998  4148.0  421.600006  963.200012  178.080002  31.230000   386.049988  0.0 349.000000  125.000000  1399.5
2020-08-15  0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   0.00    0.00    0.000000    0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000   0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000   0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.0
2020-08-16  0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.000   0.00    0.00    0.000000    0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000   0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000   0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.0
```

Entonces intenté:

```
df = df[~df.isin([0])].dropna() # getting rid of weekends where stocks = 0
df.tail()
```

Pero parece que me deshago de todas de mas lineas que necesito

```
    MCD.BA  MAQ.AX  BEKB.BR BRSR6.SA    EMBR3.SA    CWX.TO  UG.PA   VOW.F   DG.PA   VK.PA   EDL.F   TNE2.F  SRB.F   BEI.DE  BMT.SG  BSU.SG  D6H.DE  B5A.DE  3328.HK 0129.HK 3368.HK 1988.HK 3378.HK 1099.HK ANSALHSG.NS WSTCSTPAPR.NS   DATAMATICS.NS   ADANIENT.NS CIR.MI  FRAGUAB.MX  GD.MX   CL.MX   TEL.OL  BS6.SI  ITX.MC  EKTA-B.ST   3617.TW AVT CUK BEN MSFT    QCOM    IHG.L   ASHM.L  SGRO.L  BA  CAR MC.PA   RMS CDI.PA  TIF BRBY.L
2018-01-23  749.0   15.49   36.919998   15.030000   19.430000   7.09    18.745001   186.500000  87.660004   5.870   3.51    8.40    50.400002   97.800003   57.520000   35.200001   44.750000   28.6    6.72    2.11    1.13    7.32500 1.60    33.700001   28.25   316.549988  134.000000  111.377998  0.591894    240.000000  3898.0  1444.300049 186.500000  1.59    29.000000   73.360001   100.0   42.639999   68.980003   45.509998   91.900002   68.339996   5172.629883 422.200012  576.599976  335.589996  45.750000   244.600006  0.78    302.799988  108.860001  1625.5
2018-01-24  749.0   15.40   37.060001   15.790000   19.799999   7.00    18.520000   185.000000  86.959999   5.876   3.51    8.40    49.000000   96.559998   57.639999   35.400002   44.900002   27.0    6.78    2.15    1.11    7.30000 1.59    33.549999   27.75   319.850006  140.550003  111.976997  0.591894    247.199997  4066.0  1444.300049 184.000000  1.60    29.000000   72.580002   100.0   42.790001   71.120003   45.520000   91.820000   67.980003   5076.839844 433.200012  571.200012  334.690002  44.919998   241.199997  0.78    299.700012  109.120003  1621.0
2018-01-25  749.0   15.50   36.939999   15.790000   19.799999   6.96    18.450001   182.600006  87.199997   5.828   3.48    8.35    48.400002   95.040001   55.950001   35.599998   45.200001   26.9    6.71    2.16    1.17    7.05000 1.59    33.599998   28.50   315.200012  137.600006  116.827003  0.590894    247.199997  4220.0  1444.300049 181.100006  1.59    28.959999   74.000000   101.0   42.990002   70.650002   45.160000   92.330002   67.419998   5005.259766 432.000000  568.599976  343.109985  45.060001   240.149994  0.78    298.299988  109.129997  1602.5
2018-01-29  749.0   15.70   37.139999   16.240000   20.049999   6.77    18.365000   184.000000  87.559998   5.750   3.57    8.40    46.400002   95.360001   55.549999   35.000000   46.650002   26.5    6.92    2.25    1.14    7.60000 1.59    33.650002   28.25   291.899994  135.800003  116.254997  0.599892    247.199997  4206.0  1444.300049 181.350006  1.62    29.180000   75.099998   99.5    43.470001   71.669998   45.119999   93.919998   67.320000   5012.629883 430.799988  576.599976  340.820007  46.410000   252.600006  0.78    311.899994  109.300003  1614.0
```

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo que el método `dropna()` borra cuando una celda no tiene valor, pero quizás interpreta el "0" como valor, y no estaría equivocado. Voy a probar una cosa y te digo

Comment: *Pero parece que me deshago de todas de mas lineas que necesito* ¿Qué lineas necesitas? ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo de que DataFrame tratas de conseguir?

Answer (score 1):

Toma la columna MCD.BA como datetime,

```
df['MCD.BA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MCD.BA'])
```

y filtras por [dayofweek](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html), que el número corresponda a un día de la semana

```
df = df[df['MCD.BA'].dt.dayofweek.isin([0,1,2,3,4])]
```

o más simple, que no sea fin de semana (ni 5, ni 6):

```
df[~df['MCD.BA'].dt.dayofweek.isin([5,6])]
```

Comment: gracias por la resspuesta. Desafortunadamente obtengo `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: .dt se aplica sobre una columna (Serie), no sobre un DataFrame.  
Estás segura que usas  
df['MCD.BA'].dt  
y no   
df.dt  
?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente `pandas` reconoce los "zeros" como valor, por lo tanto no te borra las lineas.

`dropna()` solo funciona con celdas que estén vacías, como los NaN y los NaT.

Para lo que tu necesitas prueba esto:

```
df.drop(df[df['MAQ.AX'] == 0].index, inplace=True)
```

Esto borrará todas las filas donde la columna "MAQ.AX" sea igual a "0". Con el parámetro `inplace=True` lo que haces es modificar directamente el dataframe sin tener que crear copias nuevas o usar la asignacíon `df = df[.....]`

Adaptado de >
[Delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27360130/6493172)